# AttributeError: Commands.bot has no attribute slash_commands

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, pycord

Using pycord to add slash commands in my discord but there's an error
Here is the code

```
    import discord
    import youtube_dl
    import asyncio
    from discord.ext import commands

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    intents.message_content = True
    intents.voice_states = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

    @bot.slash_command(name='hello')
    async def hello(ctx: discord_Interaction):
      await ctx.respond('Hello there!')
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
    bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
    AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'
```

Also, I tried another fix from official documentation

```
     bot = command.Bot(intents=intents)

    @bot.slash_command(name='hello')
    async def hello(ctx: discord_Interaction):
      await ctx.respond('Hello there!')
```

yet this one gives an error

```
    bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)
    AttributeError: module 'bot' has no attribute 'slash_command'
```

I tried different versions of pycord yet the error persists. Any fix?
Ps. I haven't forgot to add `command_prefix` I just thought it wasn't necessary here

Answer (score 1):

First, choose the module: `discordpy` or `py-cord` (I prefer `py-cord` because it is more modern).

For py-cord:

> `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall py-cord`

For discord.py:

> `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall discord.py`

After, you don't need to declare `client` if you have already declared `bot` (`discord.Bot`, `discord.Client` are the same thing).

Your code should look something like this:

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.slash_command(name='hello')
async def hello(ctx: discord.Context):
  await ctx.respond('Hello there!')

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

> Note: `commands.Bot()` is used to create prefixed commands and
> `discord.Bot()` for slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

To create a slash command use the `bot.tree.command` decorator:

```py
guild = discord.Object(id=YOUR_GUILD_ID)

@bot.tree.command(guild=guild)
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("hello there")
```

Also remember to sync your slash commands:

```py
async def setup_hook():
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)

bot.setup_hook = setup_hook
```